# Expressing doubt about present versus doubt about near future

Tags: gramática, conjugación

I am a bit confused about using the conditional versus subjunctive in a certain case, essentially about expressing doubt about the present versus doubt about the near future.

For example, if I want to say "I don't think he is winning this game." I THINK it should be:   No creo que gane este juego.

Now if I want to say "I don't think he will win this game."
Is it still "No creo que gane este juego" or should it be "No creo que ganará este juego" ?

Comment: No creo que vaya a ganar?

Comment: If you use no creo, use the subjunctive. It's that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Son correctos los comentarios. Tenés que usar el subjuntivo en ambos casos para concordar con el tipo de negación que usaste al principio de la oración. El primer caso es más sencillo, simplemente lo traducimos en presente:

> I don't think **he is winning** this game.

> No creo que **[él] esté ganando** la partida.

El segundo caso puede confundir porque refiere al futuro, entonces si sólo te basás en la tabla de conjugaciones podrías creer que tendrías que conjugarlo en subjuntivo y futuro. Lo cierto es que esta conjugación es muy rara y se usa en contextos muy específicos; recordemos además que en el subjuntivo no siempre hay una correspondencia perfecta entre el tiempo con el que se nombra canónicamente a la conjugación y entre el tiempo 'verdadero', es decir aquel al que refiere el verbo visto como parte de una oración. Así que está el recurso de combinarlo con el verbo *ir* en subjuntivo y presente:

> I don't think **he will win** this game.

> No creo que **[él] vaya a ganar** la partida.

O bien, se puede directamente conjugar el verbo en presente, que en este caso sigue teniendo un sentido similar, aunque también puede usarse para situaciones más alejadas en el tiempo:

> I don't think **he will win** this game.

> No creo que **[él] gane** la partida.

Comment: Muchas gracias Tac! Tiene mucho sentido y lo entiendo muy claramente.

Answer (score 1):

In future tense we always use to go + infinitive when:

> para referirse a algo que, por las circunstancias presentes, parece seguro que va a suceder.
> *to refer to something that, by present circumstances, seems certain to happen*

<sub>*Source [burbujaespanol.com](https://burbujadelespanol.com/futuro-espanol/)*</sub>

Applied to your example:

- I don't think he (by the present circumstances) will win (seems
  certain to happen) this game.

The correct way will be:

> (Yo) No creo que (él) **vaya a ganar** este juego.